# Deleting from sqlite database - Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm not able to delete from my database for some reason. I'm trying to compare the _ID value in the database with one entered by the user in an EditText box and if it matches it should delete the whole row.

This is what I've got so far:

```
private static String[] DELETION = {_ID, TITLE, TIME, DETAILS};
private Cursor delete(){
        calendarData = new CalendarData(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = calendarData.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor idToDelete = db.query(true, TABLE_NAME, DELETION, _ID+" = "+deleteAnAppointment.getText(),
                null, null, null, null, null);
        startManagingCursor(idToDelete);
        return idToDelete;
    }

    private void selectToDelete(Cursor cursor){
        calendarData = new CalendarData(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = calendarData.getWritableDatabase();
        if(cursor.moveToNext()){
            db.delete(TABLE_NAME, _ID+" = "+deleteAnAppointment.getText(), null);
        }

    }
```

Please any help would be appreciated, my EditText input type is set to number

edit: just to make it maybe a bit more clear, I'm calling these methods in an onClick for a button like this:

```
Cursor toDelete = delete();
            selectToDelete(toDelete);
```

Edit(2): Table creation

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
                    DATE + " LONG, " +
                    TITLE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + TIME + " TEXT NOT NULL," + DETAILS + " TEXT NOT NULL);");
    }
```

Edit(3): I tried this as well as a simple approach but still nothing:

```
private void deleteAppointment(){
        calendarData = new CalendarData(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = calendarData.getWritableDatabase();

        db.delete(TABLE_NAME, _ID+" = "+deleteAnAppointment.getText(), null);


    }
```

Comment: no, no errors, just nothing happening in the database when I enter a number which matches the ID number in the database

Comment: Post your table creation statement.

Comment: The next thing to check would be to do an open query to your database and look at the data and see if it actually is what you expect it to be. Post those results next and it will provide further insight.

Comment: I know that the values are there, i.e. the user can see the _ID numbers on the screen, then when they enter the ID number they want to delete in the edittext, they hit the button and it will delete it, but it doesnt

Comment: That design is faulty and extremely error prone. You shouldn't be using an EditText for deleting the users data, it should be abstracted to the actual object it reflects. In this case, it would be a list of checkboxes for which they would like to delete. However this is beside the point. As for the issue without any further data, we can't help you.

Comment: If you use delete of sqlitedatabase, you should code like this db.delete(TABLE_NAME,"_ID = ?", deleteAnAppointment.getText())

Answer (score 0):

I see your issue. You are calling (edittext obj).getText() which does not actually return the text it returns and instance of editable. Call .toString() after and then you'll have the actual value.

This would have been easy to detect if you added a log to print your select statement... fyi

Comment: I had it as .toString() before but was trying out some new stuff, but that isn't the problem (or only problem atleast). Thanks for your help however